# Can I recycle greasy metal in the US?

Tags: recycling, waste, usa, metal

In the United States, I know that paper and plastic are often not recyclable if they are greasy.

Can I recycle metal that has vegetable grease on it surface? I'm thinking of canisters that once contained nuts.

Comment: Metal can be cleaned easily, it most likely is also melted down when being recycled - so some grease should be no hassle.

Comment: greasy paper should be able to be composted?

Comment: thanks y chung! I will look into that more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, that's really not a problem.

Recycling metal involves pre-processing.  They are concerned with contaminants like **paint** and **plating** getting into the batch.  What they use to remove paint and galvanization will certainly remove grease.

Comment: I got two great answers since I last checked! Just picked the first one as the "official answer." Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Scrap metals are not cleaned, they are melted. For steel; Zn, Sn, Pb, and others vaporize or oxidize. The most problematic is Zn as the oxide in the slag can deteriorate the refractory. Aluminum is similar except scrap aluminum containing Cu and Si will be segregated as much as possible, used for certain alloys. Copper scrap, being more valuable is separated according to the alloy to be produced. Oil, grease and paint are non-factors.

Comment: I got two great answers since I last checked! Just picked the first one as the "official answer." Thanks!

Comment: My answer  should be more or less the opposite of the first; I guess I need to wok on communication skills

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you are both saying that grease doesn't matter. Are you saying that oil/grease/paint are non-factors only for copper?

Comment: They do not matter and they are not removed. Although scrap charge is usually preheated to be certain it contains no water and for efficiency. This preheat can be high enough to burn off paint ,oil and grease.

Comment: okay, so both of you are saying it doesn't matter but for different reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Scrap yards do not accept PCBs, TVs, anything made by a railroad company, sewer covers, or equipment containing Freon. Basically other than that: weigh in, dump it, weigh out, and get paid.

Oil or grease? If you dug up some soil at a scrap yard you could make brownies.... They have water trucks to keep the dust down, but *everything* there is just so yucky that it doesn't really mater.